# Accessing .bib file from files in folders

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing my thesis and to keep stuff organized, I putted stuff in Folders. My directory looks like:

Frontmatter:     (THIS IS A FOLDER)

- asbstract.tex
- titlepage.tex
- ... and more

Mainmatter:    (THIS IS A FOLDER)

- Introduction.tex
- LiteratureReview.tex
- ... and more

Bibliography.bib

main.tex

---

In my main.tex I input the seperate files and make the reference list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside, openany]{book}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Additional math symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 

% for figures and stuff
\usepackage{graphicx}



% Header styles
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


% abbreviations
\usepackage[nopostdot,nogroupskip,toc, acronym]{glossaries} %Load glossaries package

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{rl}{RL}{Reinforcement Learning}

%Here we define a set of example acronyms
%\newglossaryentry{RL}{name={RL},description={Reinforcement Learning}}
%\newglossaryentry{DRL}{name={DRL},description={Deep Reinforcement Learning}}
%\newglossaryentry{MDP}{name={MDP},description={Markov Decision Process}}
% AI

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    \input{Frontmatter/titlepage}
    \input{Frontmatter/abstract}
    \tableofcontents
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title={List of Abbreviations}]
    
\mainmatter
    \input{Mainmatter/introduction}
    \input{Mainmatter/LiteratureReview}
    \input{Mainmatter/Background}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

If I want to cite articles in the separate files, for instance in Introduction.tex, the bibliography file is not automatically recognized. I tried to fix this by typing

```
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
```

At the beginning of each seperate file. This does work in the sense that citations are now recognized, but the full reference list is compiled in before every seperate file as well. I only want to 'load' in the bibliography.bib file. Does anyone know how to manage this?

The seperate files look like this:

```
\chapter{introduction}
here some text

\section{first section}
more text
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: hi TobiBS. Thank you taking the time to comment. I editted my post and added code. Please let me know if I can clarify any further

Comment: What do you mean with "the bibliography file is not automatically recognized"? Are you compiling `main.tex` or the files in the subfolder?

Comment: Maybe you should try [import](https://ctan.org/pkg/import)

Comment: compiling main.tex. What I mean is that when I work in introduction.tex (I work in overleaf btw), and i dont have \bibliography{Bibliography.bib} included in that file, I get the following warning when I cite. F.i. when i type \cite{Einstein}, then the warning is Citation 'Einstein' undefined on page 1. Also, when I compile main.tex in this case, the reference list is empty.

Comment: DG, how do you mean that? within my main.tex or introduction.tex?